# Mapquest API & OpenLayers markers

Tags: leaflet, openlayers-2, markers, mapquest

Not unlike others, I've found myself forced to edit some code due to MapQuest changing how they offer the openstreetmap data, and using an API Key.

Getting the key, aswell as getting up a simple leaflet map zoomed to where i wanted went easily.

Now I'm trying to add a layer of points of interest, based on a text file. I had/have the data in a file 'textfile.txt', and through OpenLayers I was able to display the markers using the following code snippet:

```
var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "Archieflijst",
            { location:"./textfile.txt",
              projection: map.displayProjection
            });
map.addLayer(pois);
```

How would I make that work now?

For reference, i'll post current code-build, without my actual API-key:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Werkterrein</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.s/mq-map.js?key=key_goes_here"></script>
    <script src="ol.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function() {
                var mapLayer = MQ.mapLayer(), map;

                map = L.map('map', {
                    layers: mapLayer,
                    center: [50.94517,3.11969],
                    zoom: 11
                });

                L.control.layers({
            'Map': mapLayer,
                    'Hybrid': MQ.hybridLayer(),
                    'Satellite': MQ.satelliteLayer(),
                    'Dark': MQ.darkLayer(),
                    'Light': MQ.lightLayer()
                }).addTo(map);

        var pois = new ol.Layer.Text( "Archieflijst",
                    { location:"./textfile.txt",
                    projection: map.displayProjection
                    });
        map.addLayer(pois);

           }





        </script>
    </head>

    <body style='border:0; margin: 0'>
        <div id='map' style='width:1100px; height:530px;'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 'textfile.txt' and 'ol.js' in the same folder.

Contents + example line for textfile.txt:

```
lat lon title   description icon    iconSize    iconOffset
51.0049363376102    3.19743523027068    Elk logo vertegenwoordigt een gerealiseerd project      icoon.png   16,16   -8,-8
```

Comment: Are you trying to migrate from OpenLayers to Leaflet? Your code seems to have classes from both. There is no class/plugin in Leaflet which corresponds to `OpenLayers.Layer.Text`, but it can easily be built. Can you post a couple of lines of the data in your textfile.txt, so that we can help you out with that.

Comment: I think you may have struck the key element of my confusion: mixing up Leaflet and OpenLayers. I had a working system in OpenLayers, but the tile support on which it relied got altered by MapQuest. I can access tiles, but it's a Leaflet plugin..  Basically I need to rebuild it in Leaflet rather then OpenLayers? And look into Leaflet's way of handling markers?

Comment: And the map (how it was, showing ugly error messages now, can be found here: http://www.demey.be/werkterrein ). Basically I want markers with 'icoon.jpg' - company logo to show up, and have it be able to build a display based on the contents of the 'description' field.

Comment: Is creating a CSV file a suitable solution for you? You could then use: https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV

Comment: I'll be looking both into CSV, ShapeFile and  GeoJSON. Basically, from an old acces-database, we've made a TAB-file we use in QGis, but also made the export from there to a txt file for use with OpenLayers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your existing text file, along with the [Leaflet GeoCSV](https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV) plugin, with the following code.
Do note that I'm using jQuery to load the text file. Additionally, you can replace the OSM Layer with your MapQuest Layer.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
<script src="leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet.geocsv-src.js"></script>



<style>
#mapDiv{
    width:1200px;
    height: 700px;
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    background: black;
    background-image:url("openlayerbg.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:30px;
}
.leaflet-popup-tip{
    background: black;
}
</style>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="mapDiv"> </div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        var map = L.map('mapDiv').setView([50.94517,3.11969], 10);

        //Add osm Layer

        var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                minZoom : 8,
                maxZoom : 12,
                attribution : 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            });
        osm.addTo(map);

        //load the text file
        $.get('textfile.txt', function(csvContents) {
            var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {
                  titles: ['lat', 'lon', 'title','description', 'icon'],
                  longitudeTitle: 'lon',
                  fieldSeparator: '\t',
                  lineSeparator: '\n',
                  deleteDobleQuotes: true,
                  firstLineTitles: true,
                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties['title']);
                  },
                  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                        return L.marker(latlng, {
                          icon:L.icon({
                            iconUrl: feature.properties['icon'],
                            iconSize: [16,16]
                          })
                        });
                      }
                });
            map.addLayer(geoLayer);
          });
 });


    </script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Where do I insert that block? Before the </script> tag? And I'll assume I need to reference jQuery like this? : <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: @TimCouwelier: I've added the complete Code

Comment: Map works, markers arent working yet. I'll try to figure out if it's a silly hickup on my end first (dependencies and what not), if that fails i'll upload my entire folder with the page  +the entire text file that holds the markers. Many thanks for your efforts thus far.

Comment: is 'deleteDobleQuotes' intentional, or a typo? I notice you assign 'lon' for longitude, but not 'lat' for lattitude?  For a limited time, the combined files I'm using are uploaded here:  https://we.tl/A2A0KCMvhF , as that may yield more convenient troubleshooting.

Comment: `deleteDobleQuotes` is not required for your data, and you can remove it; I had to give only `lon`, because the default field for that in the library was `lng`. This problem does not exist for latitude; The only thing missing in your code, is that you need to place `openlayerbg.jpg` in the same folder. Then you will get the image in the popup.

Comment: Added the image, but the issue wasn't the contents of the popup, it's the markers not showing up on the map...

Comment: @TimCouwelier: Are you putting this code in some web server? or running it from the file system? Running the app from your file system won't work.

Comment: Was running it from file system. Uploaded it, and it works indeed. Thanks for your helping, giving this the checkmark.